# OpenMP Task and Taskwait constructs

Tags: c++, c, openmp

I am implementing a runtime library for a very small subset of OpenMP and I am getting stuck with the semantics of the Task and Taskwait constructs.

For the purposes of understanding, I created the code example below. In it, shouldn't the system enter in a live-lock situation? For the 'task2' tasks are waiting to consume data produced by 'task1' task however 'task1' is "taskwaiting" for all it's children to finish? When I try this snippet with GOMP and Intel OMP the program finishes execution normally.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int result;

void task2(int* res) {
    printf("Task2... %p\n", res);

}

void task1(int* res) {
    printf("Task1... %p\n", &result);

    #pragma omp task depend(in:result)
    task2(&result);

    #pragma omp taskwait
    printf("Task1 finishing...\n");
}

int main() {
    int res = 0;

    #pragma omp parallel
    #pragma omp single
    {
        printf("Res addr = %p\n", &result);

        #pragma omp task depend(inout:result)
        task1(&result);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `task depend` clauses only apply to sibling tasks. In that case `task2` is not a sibling, but a child task of `task1`.

Quoting the relevant section of [OpenMP 4.5](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/openmp-4.5.pdf):

> [2.13.9] For the **in** *dependence-type*, if the storage location of at least one of
>   the list items is the same as the storage location of a list item
>   appearing in an **out** or **inout** *dependence-type* list of a `task` 
>   construct from which a **sibling task** was previously generated, then the
>   generated task will be a dependent task of that sibling task.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer, that makes sense. I have one more question though: are tasks created by other tasks immediatelly executed?

Comment: Maybe, but not guaranteed. "The encountering thread may immediately execute the task, or defer its execution. In the latter case, any thread in the team may be assigned the task."

Comment: So, do you think that this is implementation dependent? Or have any idea about how that is decided?

Comment: It would certainly be implementation dependent. I guess it first depends if there is a free thread in the current team. In that case I'd guess this thread starts executing immediately. If there is no free thread, there needs to be some heuristic to figure out whether the active thread executes the new task or continues it's current task. That might depend on static analysis. Of course all this has to consider dependencies. Further, an implementation could probably decide to "inline" a task that it knows is very short even without the extra tasking overhead.